# Regression with non-zero mean errors

Tags: regression, distributions, linear-model

I want to fit a linear regression model of the type

$$y_j= x^{\top}_j\beta +\epsilon_j,\,\,\, j=1,\dots,n,$$

However, [the distribution](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sks/research/papers/sahudeybranco.pdf) I am using for modelling $\epsilon_j$ does not have mean zero, although it has location 0, and the mean of this distribution is no available in closed-form. Is there any problem with using this kind of models? I am aware that the fitted model would not be interpreted as a mean response.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by 'linear regression model of the type ...'? Ordinary least squares? And what is the distribution of errors you are using?

Comment: Any shift in the distribution of the $\epsilon_j$ will be taken up by the inclusion of an intercept term in the model.  You should give details of your model for the distribution of $\epsilon_j$.

Comment: @psarka I am going to use maximum likelihood estimation. The distribution  I am using is a member of the skew-elliptical family.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Good point. I have added the paper I am using.

Comment: Maximum likelihood should be a good start!

Comment: The paper you attached specifically discusses fitting linear regression with skewed-elliptical errors. Why don't you want to follow their lead? (especially when they even offer to send the code)

Comment: @psarka I have no problem with the implementation. My question is specifically regarding the problems with using non-zero mean errors. They say "Often the error distribution in a regression model is taken to have mean zero". My question is: what happens in the "not-so-often" cases?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen you should post that as an answer because it is the correct answer as far as I know